# MySQL foreign key ERROR 1025

Tags: mysql

If I have 3 tables let say table1, table2, and table3.

```
table1: userID is a primary key.
table2: userID is a foreign key to table1.
table3: I can't get userID to be a foreign key to table 1?

ERROR 1025: Error on rename of.... (errno: 152)
```

What might the problem be? userID are all INT and all tables using InnoDB...

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statements you are attempting to use.

Comment: please post output of `show create table table1` and same for table2 and table3

Comment: I figured it - foreign key names can't be the same in other tables it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your table like

```
create table table3(a int not null, foreign key(a) references table1 (a))
```

should work fine.

Also, try `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` you will get more info on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Had #1025 too, my problem was collation. Fields that you are trying to associate with FK must have the same collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
"For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same."